# SetText method on JTextField from return value of a method works on one method but not on another identical method

Tags: java

I think the title pretty much can speak for itself.

In my ActionPerformed method, on the two first statements of the conditionals:

```
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "GBP"));
            otherLabel.setText("GBP");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "GBP"));
        }
```

... only the top one (if) works eventhough i have set calculateFromNok and calculateToNok to be exactly identical. The top one sets the return value of the calculateFromNok method as setText in the otherTextField, and i want to do the same but opposite when only otherTextField is set. But as i said, eventhough both methods are identical only the setText of otherTextField works. I have set them to be identical to check if it works then, and just to have said it the currency mathemathics i will deal with later.

Here is my entire code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ValutaKalkulator implements ActionListener
{
private JFrame frame;
private JOptionPane optionPane;
private JButton buttonRemoveNok;
private JButton removeOther;
private JButton removeBoth;
private JButton exitButton;
private JButton usdButton;
private JButton sekButton;
private JButton gbpButton;
private JButton eurButton;
private JLabel nokLabel;
private JLabel otherLabel;
private JTextField otherTextField;
private JTextField nokTextField;

public ValutaKalkulator() 
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    frame.setTitle("VALUTAKALKULATOR");
    buttonRemoveNok = new JButton("Fjern NOK");
    removeOther = new JButton("Fjern annen valuta");
    removeBoth = new JButton("Fjern begge");
    exitButton = new JButton("Avslutt");
    usdButton = new JButton("USD");
    sekButton = new JButton("SEK");
    gbpButton = new JButton("GBP");
    eurButton = new JButton("EUR");
    nokLabel = new JLabel("NOK");
    otherLabel = new JLabel("Annen valuta");
    otherTextField = new JTextField();
    nokTextField = new JTextField();

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("dlr.png");
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    buttonRemoveNok.addActionListener(this);
    removeOther.addActionListener(this);
    removeBoth.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    usdButton.addActionListener(this);
    sekButton.addActionListener(this);
    gbpButton.addActionListener(this);
    eurButton.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    JPanel pnlNorth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));

    pnlNorth.add(nokLabel);
    pnlNorth.add(nokTextField);
    pnlNorth.add(otherLabel);
    pnlNorth.add(otherTextField);

    pnlCenter.add(gbpButton);
    pnlCenter.add(eurButton);
    pnlCenter.add(usdButton);
    pnlCenter.add(sekButton);

    pnlSouth.add(buttonRemoveNok);
    pnlSouth.add(removeOther);
    pnlSouth.add(removeBoth);
    pnlSouth.add(exitButton);

    frame.add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

}

public String calculateFromNok(String nokValueString, String toValue)
{
    double result = 0;
    double nokValue = Double.valueOf(nokValueString);

    switch(toValue)
    {
        case "GBP":
        result = nokValue * 0.109690;
        break;

        case "EUR":
        result = nokValue * 0.093158;
        break;

        case "USD":
        result = nokValue * 0.085537;
        break;

        case "SEK":
        result = nokValue * 97.03 / 100;
        break;
    }

    String resultString = Double.toString(result);
    return resultString;
}


public String calculateToNok(String nokValueString, String toValue)
{
    double result = 0;
    double nokValue = Double.valueOf(nokValueString);

    switch(toValue)
    {
        case "GBP":
        result = nokValue * 0.109690;
        break;

        case "EUR":
        result = nokValue * 0.093158;
        break;

        case "USD":
        result = nokValue * 0.085537;
        break;

        case "SEK":
        result = nokValue * 97.03 / 100;
        break;
    }

    String resultString = Double.toString(result);
    return resultString;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String text = event.getActionCommand();
    String txt = nokTextField.getText();

    switch(text)
    {
        case "Fjern NOK":
        nokTextField.setText("");
        break;

        case "Fjern annen valuta":
        otherTextField.setText("");
        otherLabel.setText("Annen valuta");
        break;

        case "Fjern begge":
        nokTextField.setText("");
        otherTextField.setText("");
        otherLabel.setText("Annen valuta");
        break;

        case "Avslutt":
        System.exit(0);
        break;

        case "GBP":
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "GBP"));
            otherLabel.setText("GBP");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "GBP"));
        }

        else if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive bare ett beløp!");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive ett beløp!");
        }
        break;

        case "EUR":
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "EUR"));
            otherLabel.setText("EUR");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "EUR"));

        }

        else if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive bare ett beløp!");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive ett beløp!");
        }
        break;

        case "USD":
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "USD"));
            otherLabel.setText("USD");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "USD"));
        }

        else if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive bare ett beløp!");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive ett beløp!");
        }
        break;

        case "SEK":
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "SEK"));
            otherLabel.setText("SEK");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "SEK"));
        }

        else if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive bare ett beløp!");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            optionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Du må skrive ett beløp!");
        }
        break;
    }

}

public boolean checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty()
{
    if(nokTextField.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()
{
    if(otherTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

The error message i get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
empty String
```

And that should mean that its trying to format an empty string into a Double i guess? But still, the formatting from double to string works on the other method without errors...

Maybe that was abit poorly explained, but i hope you understand what i mean.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a small mistake in this part:

```
case "GBP":
        if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            otherTextField.setText(calculateFromNok(txt, "GBP"));
            otherLabel.setText("GBP");
        }

        else if(checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty()) {
            nokTextField.setText(calculateToNok(txt, "GBP"));
        }
```

Here in the `else if` condition Suppose if `nokTextField` is empty then in `String txt = nokTextField.getText();` , here `txt` stores an empty String. So in execution of the `else if` condition First Function `checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty()` will return `true` and consider that another function returns `true` as well. So this condition gets satisfied and then `calculateToNok(txt, "GBP")` function will be called.

Now in that function you have a statement `double nokValue = Double.valueOf(nokValueString);` which will try to convert that empty `string` to `double` and causing the `Exception`.

So I think you have made in that condition of `else if` part. Condition should be :

```
else if(!checkIfNokTextFieldIsEmpty() && !checkIfOtherTextFieldIsEmpty())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i do have this exact line under the else if statement you are referring to. What your else if statement is saying is that if both fields are empty then *do something*, which my next statement does; shows a JOptionPane telling the user that both fields are empty.

Comment: I didn't know what is the right condition which fits there. It's your logic but the thing I have done is pointed the mistake which causes the `Exception` in the code. You can redefine that function as per your need.

Comment: Right, i catch your drift!

Comment: Thanks alot dude, fixed it ! It was right in front of my eyes this whole time!